# Spring-Data Neo4J @Repository @Query not working

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-repositories

The following is the stacktrace generated after the exception is thrown:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-18 10:45:31.825 ERROR 16349 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryPropertyReferenceController' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/sean/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.1.0.RC2/11b3ab6953b3a0f6a433e48be1b0d2db668602c5/spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.0.RC2.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'matchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:766) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:217) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:829) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M3.jar:2.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M3.jar:2.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:421) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M3.jar:2.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:340) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M3.jar:2.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M3.jar:2.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1279) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M3.jar:2.1.0.M3]
    at io.sciro.leaderdata.LeaderDataApp.main(LeaderDataApp.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'matchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:290) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1149) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:854) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:757) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'matchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'matchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1743) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1091) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.repositories(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:242) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.0.RC2.jar:3.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb148bd0.CGLIB$repositories$5(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.0.RC2.jar:3.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb148bd0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e615e97.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.0.RC2.jar:3.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb148bd0.repositories(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.0.RC2.jar:3.1.0.RC2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:545) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.java:66) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1739) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    ... 55 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My repository is written as follows:

```
package io.sciro.leaderdata.repo;

import io.sciro.leaderdata.domain.Match;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "match", collectionResourceRel = "match")
public interface MatchRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Match, Long> {

    //If I delete the line below, everything works fine.        
    Match findMatchByCodeName(String codeName);

    //If I delete the line below, everything works fine.
    Iterable<Match> findMatchesByCodeName(@Param("codeName")  String codeName);
}
```

My entity/domain:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Match {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String codeName;
    private Long round;
    private String me;
    private String pc;
    private Character result;
    private Date timestamp;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastUpdated;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date created;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

I have the following Gradle Script:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.M3'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'io.sciro'
version = '0.1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}


ext {
    springBootAdminVersion = '2.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:5.0.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:3.1.1-RC1')
    compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-http-driver:3.1.1-RC1')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
//    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client')
    compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-server')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core

//    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix')
//    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard')
//    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client')
//    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-parent
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-parent', version: 'Finchley.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-dependencies:${springBootAdminVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? I'm kinda stuck on this issue now. An alternative solution that worked for me, was to delete these two lines of code from the MatchRepo interface:

```
    //If I delete the line below, everything works fine.        
    Match findMatchByCodeName(String codeName);

    //If I delete the line below, everything works fine.
    Iterable<Match> findMatchesByCodeName(@Param("codeName")  String codeName);
```

I just use findAll() method extended from the extended Neo4jRepository interface & then use java-8 stream to filter for the Match object that matches the codeName. An ugly solution indeed. If anyone knows how to fix this issue the right way, please help.

Comment: you need to add queries with `@Query` for each repo method

Comment: @benjaminc I tried that as well, the issues is still there. :-( Doesn't it have something to do some missing/clashing dependencies, or the version of Spring-Cloud? In the Neo4j Spring Data examples & Documentation they also did the same.

Comment: have you added `@EnableNeo4jRepositories` somewhere in configuration class

Comment: @benjaminc Yes, I added that annotation in the configuration class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* it seems that you're using incompatible versions of Spring-Data-Commons and Spring Data Neo4j. You're overwriting the version of SDN to 5.0.9 but not the Release Train Version.

Anyway, recommended naming scheme is something like this for derived method names:

```
package io.sciro.leaderdata.repo;

import io.sciro.leaderdata.domain.Match;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "match", collectionResourceRel = "match")
public interface MatchRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Match, Long> {

    Match findOneByCodeName(String codeName);

    Iterable<Match> findAllByCodeName(@Param("codeName")  String codeName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that fact. it was indeed a version mismatch in the dependencies.